# Anyone know how to get past this Kerberos configuration warning in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, kerberos

I'm trying to run a simple sorting job on Hadoop-2.0.0 in standalone mode, but every time I try, I get this warning:

```
 WARN util.KerberosName: Kerberos krb5 configuration not found, setting default realm to empty
```

How do I set the necessary configuration?  I can't find any information about this issue on the Apache website.  Does anyone know how I can fix this problem?

Comment: Do you have Kerberos installed at all?

Comment: Does it come pre-installed with Linux?  If not, then I guess I don't...

Comment: Not on Debian or Ubuntu, in any case. `sudo apt-get install heimdal-clients` should do the trick, but you might need to properly configure it to work with an actual cluster.

Answer (score 0):

on RHEL , the Kerberos clients are installed by default. Check to see whether you have /etc/krb5.conf correctly configured. 
Also are you using Hadoop with Kerberos enabled? Do you need it in your environment?

Answer (score 0):

You can point to your own krb5.conf file 
using KRB5_CONFIG environment variable.

E.g.

```
KRB5_CONFIG=/var/tmp/krb5.conf
```